# Why I get different answer when I use data.getData() vs data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Right now I'm trying to implement pick a multiple photos from gallery.
I already have the logic when is just to pick one photo from gallery that is works well.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
```

and when I debug, I'm getting the format of this way:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F26/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fpng/1642097413
```

for then use:

```
Cursor cursor;
 int columnIndex;
 String picturePath = "";
 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
 
 cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

and everything works well for single photo.

but, when I tried to implement the logic for multiple photos where I use:

```
ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();// where I get all the photos I selected
if (clipData != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                    try {
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri selectedImage = item.getUri();
                        ....
```

I'm getting the format of `selectedImage` as:

[image]

that is different vs:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F26/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fpng/1642097413
```

[extra information]:

**Way to pick just one photo from gallery**

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

**Way to pick multiple photos from gallery**

```
private static final int CODE_MULTIPLE_IMG_GALLERY = 2;
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "selecciona varias imagenes"), CODE_MULTIPLE_IMG_GALLERY);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the [Activity Result APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), which provide a [prebuilt intent for selecting images](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents) that handles all of this for you parsing logic for you? Note that none of this MediaStore stuff is required at all - the Uri is enough for everything you want to do with it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yep, this project where I'm working is legacy, so, I trying to re use the logic that has inside of the project because my concern if I use something different I could broke something for some incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting the format of selectedImage as... that is different vs:

So? You are going to get `Uri` values with many different structures, based on the apps that handle the request.

Your problem is not the way the `Uri` looks. Your problem is in assuming that every `Uri` can be queried for a `DATA` column, and that the result of that query is a filesystem path that is usable. Neither of those things is true.

Your `ACTION_PICK` code is unreliable:

- There is no requirement that you can use the filesystem path. On many versions of Android, `MediaStore` will have filesystem access to content that your app cannot reach via the filesystem, even if you knew the path.
- `DATA` can return `null`, due to some poorly-written apps that populate `MediaStore`. I have not heard of this problem in recent years, so perhaps it is less of a concern than it used to be.

However, the query-for-`DATA` script-kiddie hack will *at most* work for a `Uri` that you get from `MediaStore`, such as via `ACTION_PICK`. It will not work for a `Uri` value that you get from anything else, such as `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

So, as Ian suggests, use the `Uri` correctly. If your objective is to load the image, pass the `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.). Otherwise, use `ContentResolver` with the `Uri`, such as `openInputStream()` and `getType()`. This will work with any `Uri` pointing to an image, whether from `ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or something else.